# How to reconcile 6:146 with the laws of Chelev in Judaism?

Tags: quran, judaism

This question is regarding the verse:

> And to those who are Jews We prohibited every animal of uncloven hoof; and of the cattle and the sheep **We prohibited to them their fat, except what adheres to their backs or the entrails or what is joined with bone.** [By] that We repaid them for their injustice. And indeed, We are truthful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:146](http://quran.com/6/146)</sup>

According to Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelev), the forbidden fat or Chelev in Judaism are :

> Kidney fats : The fats surrounding the kidneys are called chelev
> hakloyoth, and are considered non-kosher.
>
> Abdominal fats : The sheet of fat which is covering the interior of
> the abdominopelvic cavity is real chelev, except at some regions where
> it is covered with steak, not with skin or tendon. However even where
> it is covered with meat, there is some fat which is still forbidden,
> since it could occasionally get uncovered while the animal
> walks[clarification needed]. Therefore, one must be well trained in
> order to identify kosher fat.
>
> Digestive system fats : There are many fats around the digestive
> organs such as the stomach and intestines, and one must be highly
> educated and trained in order to identify them.
>
> Tail fat The tail fat of the fat-tailed sheep, called alyah in Hebrew,
> is a large fatty membrane located on the hindquarters of certain
> breeds of sheep. The Torah uses the term chelev of this fat, but only
> in the sense of "the good part"; its consumption is permitted. The
> Karaites, however, understand this fat to literally be forbidden
> chelev, and thus do not allow eating the tail fat. Rabbi Judah HaLevi,
> in his work The Kuzari, questioned the practicality of the Karaite
> position: "Where exactly does [the prohibited fat] end? Some might
> prohibit only the tip of the sheep tail, while others the entire hind
> part."

I need help refuting this supposed contradiction. According to the Qur'an, fats that are in the intestines and surrounding the bones were Kosher for the Jews but what we read is definitely not the case. Fats in the intestines and surrounding the bone i.e. tendon are forbidden.

Comment: Is it really so hard to spend 2 seconds to mark your quotes and properly format your question?

Comment: It might be relevant to note that a lot of the Kosher laws are derived from the Talmud (writing of priests) rather than just the Torah or prophetic commands. They tended to increase the prohibition to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

The Quran informs us of what was forbidden to them in reality, and it is quite possible for the present Jewish law to differ because it has undergone Tahrif.

> #### يحرفون الكلم عن مواضعه ونسوا حظا مما ذكروا به
>
> They distort words from their [proper] usages and have forgotten a portion of that of which they were reminded.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:13](http://quran.com/5/13)</sup>

Even if we are to suppose that the Jewish law is preserved, it is naive to so quickly conclude that there is a contradiction between it and this verse as there is a variety of fat in this area, some of which is chelev and some is shuman, and on some there is difference of opinion.

There are also details in the interpretation of the verse, for example the verse can also be interpreted to mean that all three شحوم (fat), الحوايا (entrails) and ما اختلط بعظم (joined to the bones) were haram and only ما حملت ظهورهما (what adheres to their backs) was halal:

> وقيل : إن الاستثناء في التحليل إنما هو ما حملت الظهور خاصة ، وقوله : أو الحوايا أو ما اختلط بعظم معطوف على المحرم . والمعنى : حرمت عليهم شحومهما أو الحوايا أو ما اختلط بعظم ; إلا ما حملت الظهور فإنه غير محرم
>
> And it is said: The exception is in the permission of "what adheres to their backs" specifically, and the saying: "or the entrails or what is joined with bone" is a conjunction to the prohibition. And hence the meaning is: Forbidden to them was fat or the entrails or what is joined with bone ; except what adheres to their backs for it was not forbidden
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura6-aya146.html)</sup>

Some other relevant exegesis narrated for the verse includes:

> عن السدي قوله: (حرمنا عليهم شحومهما)، قال: الثرب وشحم الكليتين
>
> Narrated from as-Suddi about: "We prohibited to them their fat", he said: The omentum and fat on the kidneys
>
> عن أبي صالح قال: الألية، مما حملت ظهورهما
>
> Narrated from Abu Saleh: The tail of the fat-tailed sheep, is "what adheres to their backs"
>
> عن ابن جريج: (أو ما اختلط بعظم)، قال: شحم الألية بالعُصْعُص, فهو حلال. وكل شيء في القوائم والجنب والرأس والعين قداختلط بعظم, فهو حلال
>
> Narrated from Ibn Jurayj regarding: "what is joined with bone", He said: the fat of the tail of the sheep, for it is halal. And the fat of the legs, head, eyes their fat is joined to bone so it is halal
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabary](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura6-aya146.html#tabary)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented due to how short my answer is, but I lack reputation.

The Quran also says that the Christians and Jews corrupted the books revealed to them over time. Hence this contradiction can be resolved if we assume that the current Jewish laws have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

One Rabbi stated:

"Chelev refers to the outer layer of fat called suet. The prohibited chelev is the abdominal fat on the stomach, kidney, and flank. It can be peeled away like a skin. The rest of the fat which is permissible is called shuman."

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47791/are-we-not-supposed-to-eat-fat

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968263/jewish/Chapter-7.htm

Moses Maimonedes states:

9
The fat of the heart and the fat of all of the small intestines are permitted. They are considered like shuman which is permitted fat with the exception of the top of the intestine that is next to the maw and is the beginning of the small intestines. The fat must be scraped off it.22 This is the fat of the small intestines that is forbidden. There are some of the Geonim who say that the top of the intestine from which the fat must be scraped off is the large intestine,23i.e., the colon from which feces are excreted which is the last of the digestive organs.

It seems from a preliminary analysis that the permission of the entrails is what is mentioned above(the small intestines.)

http://religion.atspace.com/Judaismfood03blood.htm

"Maimonides explains what parts of the animal are included in these designated areas from which fat is forbidden.[15] It is only fat that is on the flank or kidney that is forbidden, not the fat that is covered by meat or inside the kidney."

Note: these articles are written by Moses Maimonedes who is a Rabbi from the Islamic golden Age. Most of Rabbinic Judaism consists of opinions written down after the time of Jesus. The Jews in Arabia at the time of the Prophet were probably mainly  Sadducees, a different sect, which may be the ancestors of the Karaite Jews of today. There were many different Jewish sects before Islam and before Jesus: The Essenes, the Rabbinic Jews, the Sadducees, the Zealots etc.  Orthodox Judaism descends from Rabbinic Judaism which descends from Pharisee Judaism, not the other sects. Additionally there were a wide range of views within Rabbinic Judaism about many aspects of Jewish law.

The fat that is forbidden is not that which is around the bones, it seems, from reading Moses Maimonedes text.